# Connecting to remote Mysql databases from Php scripts

Tags: php, mysql

I have two websites (managed separately with Cpanel). I want to use a database on one host from another.

Domains and their mysql ports are: abc.com:2082 and xyz.com:2082.

I would like to use the database on abc.com from a Php script running on xyz.com.  However when I try to connect to the database, the connection is showing an error: "Error".

Comment: WHat error is it showing? Be specific and edit it onto your question, not as a comment

Comment: Also lots of hosters will disable this ability. Check that it is actually possible with the host of `abc.com` before even starting the process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, You can do it in two ways first connecting database using database credential. in that case, you need to enable mysql remote permission . if provide % then anyone from any ip address can connect with your database.

Secondly, You can use restful api to exchange data in between. to know more about restful api search in the stackoverflow.

Comment: where I have to place % ?

Comment: http://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/how-to-whitelist-your-ip-in-cpanel-for-remote-mysql-access